What popular online communities exist that permit sharing links and are relevant to cogsci.se?
I know a bit about Reddit (see discussion on meta here). Key features for this discussion include the ability to post links and the existence of large communities interested in cognitive science, psychology and related areas. However, I realise there is a whole world of social network sites out there.
What other online communities exist that permit sharing and voting on links that pertain to cognitive science or pscyhology?

there are a few psychology and neuroscience circles on G+ that a number of people seem to follow. If you belong to those circles, then an advertisement through G+ will travel well.

I really like G+ idea. I've added a meta question on the topic: http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/140

Is there a reason this is a separate question from the earlier one? (http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/109/21) We could merge them and keep one of them as a faq up to date.

Less Wrong is one.  It is less academic and tends to frown on bare links, being at least as interested in the poster's reasons for posting the link.  Someone posted a link to cogsci.stackexchange there yesterday, which is how I got here.  Less Wrong is built on the reddit software.
Hacker News is more computer, especially web, oriented but occasionally has good AI, math, and practical psychology (mostly motivation-type) links.

Thanks. I hadn't heard of less wrong before. It looks interesting.
